# $ajax.success issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am retruning a string from the webmethod that is a table. The success method on the $.ajax is hit but does not insert the retruned result into the specified element.

```
 success: function(result){
          $('#divSubjectQuestions').html(result);
  },
```

when I insert some string of html then it is rendered but this code is not working.

Edit:

```
   int SubjectId = Convert.ToInt32(sSubjectId);
    DataTable QuestionsTable = QuestionDataAccess.RetrieveSubjectQuestion(SubjectId);

    string head = "<table class='gridstyle' cellspacing='0' rules='all' border='1'  style='border-collapse:collapse;width: 100%;'><tr class='headerclass'><th scope='col'>Subject l Questions</th></tr>";
    string body = "";
    foreach (DataRow row in QuestionsTable.Rows)
    {
        body += " <tr><td> <a  href='QuestionDisplay.aspx?Id=" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(1) + "'style='font-size:Small;text-decoration:none;'>" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "</a><br /><span  style='font-size:XX-Small;'>" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(2) + "</span>&nbsp;<span  style='color:Gray;font-size:XX-Small;'>Boosts" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(5) + "</span>&nbsp;<span  style='font-size:XX-Small;'>" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(4) + "</span>&nbsp;<span  style='font-size:XX-Small;'>" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(3) + "</span>&nbsp;<span  style='font-size:XX-Small;'>" + row.ItemArray.GetValue(6) + "</span></td></tr>";
    }
   // return head + body + "</table>";
    return "<p>boom!</b>";
```

Comment: Can you show us your html markup?

Comment: what does the console say if you do console.log(result);

Comment: Try to alert the result from server and check you console log if any errors?

Comment: if you notice at this time I have commented the complicated part. and I am returning only '<P>boom!</p>'. but still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was returning json data so checking  the result with console.log(result). I found the json object which had attached the result to "d" variable. 
 Then accessing result.d solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess without seeing any markup or what your data looks like but try:

```
 success: function(result){
          $('#divSubjectQuestions').html(result[0]);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Might've been that you have other Ajax calls on the same page.. In that sort of case it is recommended to use different variables inside the function ...
E.g.
     success: function(ajax1) ......

EDIT 
1. Check the syntax of the function you are calling. If it is working or not.
2. Once 1. is done, put an alert("HH"); in the success function and check if you see an alert box when you do the ajax call. If no alert box can be seen then it means there is an error with the jquery code. If you see the alert box, then there is either a conflict with the jquery code or a syntax error.

Comment: but why is this a problem in the first place. These variables have nothing to do with each other.